# How to specify inputs

Tags: java

please help in this code to specify the input to integers only
................................................................

```
        int shape=0;
        boolean inp=false;
        while (! inp) {
            try 
            {
                shape = (int)(System.in.read()-'0');

            }//try
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("error");
                System.out.println("Please enter the value again:");
            }//catch
                if ((shape == 1) || (shape == 2)) {
                inp = true;
            }//if
        }//while
```

Comment: You can not force user to enter a specific input in console mode.

Comment: Use Integer.parse and then validate the resulting Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the answer and put in the complete code. It works now (tested it). Using the BufferedReader allows you to read real `Strings` (that's why it was stuck in a endless loop before )

```
    int shape = 0;
    boolean inp = false;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (!inp) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Type in a number");
            shape = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());  // parse the string explicitly
            System.out.println("thanks");
        }//try
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
            System.out.println("Please enter the value again:");
        }//catch
        catch (NumberFormatException e) // here you catch the exception if anything but a number was entered
        {
            System.out.println("error");
            System.out.println("Please enter the value again:");
        }//catch
        System.out.println("Shape = " + shape);
        if ((shape == 1) || (shape == 2)) {
            System.out.println("should be true");
            inp = true;
        }//if
```

Comment: it gives me this error

no suitable method found for parseInt(int)
    method Integer.parseInt(String) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion)
    method Integer.parseInt(String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Comment: Well you could *force* the input to be a `String` like this: `Integer.parseInt(""+System.in.read());`

Comment: ok the error is gone , but it's not catching any errors when i enter a letter, and goes in an infinite loop

Comment: I edited my answer. Sorry I left some System.outs – but maybe they help you see what is happening, too :)

Answer (score 2):

If the only valid input is `1` or `2` then I would just limit to those exact characters
(edit: this has been tested and works):

```
char c = '-'; //invalid character to default
while (! (c == '1' || c == '2'))
{
   System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2:");
   c = (char) System.in.read();
   System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: yes this is working , but i can't use char only integers ..
it's an assignment project

Comment: Well then that's unfortunate, because they're teaching you bad practice. I'm going to share something with you that I really wish someone had told me when I was learning to program: if you're not going to do math with it, don't treat it as a number. Ever. You're opening yourself up for all sorts of validation nightmares and strange errors. Try to avoid doing something the wrong way just because someone told you to.

Comment: Thanks for your advice , i will keep it on my mind always :) 
as a level one learner they are restricting us to follow some rules and some times they don't even accept codes outside the course. 
but for me to develop myself i am trying every possible way to write a code .

Answer (score 0):

```
    Integer i = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2:");
        try {
            i = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            if(i==1 || i==2){
                System.out.println("Success! :)");
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO Exception");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Invalid input");
        }     
    }
```